# Draggable flatlist for React Native WEB

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web, expo-web, react-native-draggable-flatlist

I'm using [this (react-native-draggable-flatlist)](https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist) library to implement a draggable flat list in React Native and React Native Web using EXPO, natively it works perfectly, but on the web it has some problems, has anyone managed to implement it correctly or does they know a way to solve this problem?

Native:

[image: NATIVE]

WEB:

[image: WEB]